# Reusable Try/Catch Block

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote the following method thinking that it would allow me to pass in a method call to be wrapped within a try catch. I'm trying to avoid placing the same try/catch boiler plate coding throughout my application. I already have 20 plus calls and by the time we are finished there will be hundreds of calls.

```
protected T CallRepository<T>(T repositoryMethod)
{
    try
    {
        return repositoryMethod;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
        throw new DatabaseException();
    }
}
```

The calling method looks like:

```
var results = CallRepository<VisitLogDTO>(visitLogRepository.AddVisit(visitLogDTO));
```

I didn't realize at first that this isn't working as expected. What is happening is the results are being wrapped in the try/catch but not the call to the method. If I get a database error or any error from the visitLogRepository then I the original error and not the new DatabaseExeception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do not call the method. You pass in the result of `visitLogRepository.AddVisit(visitLogDTO)`. What you want is that your CallRepository takes a Func<> paramter.

Comment: There is some very good information here and for now my problem is solved and I greatly appreciate the help and I'm amazed with how quickly help arrived. I'm going to look into DI Interception and see if I can make use of it but for now I'm using WeSt & Eren Ersönmez advice for the Func<T>. I tried using Func<> before with no success. I was missing the lambda call which makes all the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass in a `Func<T>`, not `T`:

```
protected T CallRepository<T>(Func<T> repositoryMethod)
{
    try
    {
        return repositoryMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
var results = CallRepository(() => visitLogRepository.AddVisit(visitLogDTO));
```

Comment: +1. Note that instead of reinventing wheel it would be better to use logging/interception functionality of DI framework your app should be using...

Comment: I'm working on converting to Func<T>. Currently I'm getting errors because I still have a return type that it's unhappy about. I'll keep playing.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Unity for the Dependency Injection. I'm not familiar with a built in logging/interception that will allow me to catch the data layer error, log it, then rethrow a friendly error that I will again catch on the MVC layer and redirect the user to a friendly error page. Other than Unity, I can't add other third party NuGet packages as we have a very very strict security posture where I work. If it's something that is part of Unity than I'm interested.

Comment: @CubeRoot Unity does Dependancy Injection, but one other thing it also does is called [Interception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx). In fact on the page I just linked they show how to write a logging interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems that the AddVisit method is called outside your CallRepository Method.
Try using an Action Delegate as a Method Parameter and call that Delegate in the Method to make sure the call is done within the try catch.
Then use a Lambda Expression to call it:

```
private handleException(Action myAction)
{
    try
    {
        myAction();
    }
    catch[...]
}
```

Call:

```
 handleException( () => { int result = FunctionThatThrowsException(); } )
```

Best
Lumo

Comment: Is this going to allow for return types? Most of the method calls return data.